# Ja nao é possivel por som a tocar automaticamente em todos os broswers?

Tags: áudio

boa tarde, pelo que percebi, o chrome ja nao deixa meter o som a dar em autoplay ?
eu pretenderia que o som desse em autoplay em todos os browers? isso é possivel?

```
<iframe src="dino talk.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio">
</iframe> 
    <audio autoplay loop  id="playAudio">
    <source src="dino talk.mp3">
</audio>
```